# как распарсить header в android java

Tags: java, android, парсер, header

есть вот такой стринг в котрый я поместил header                 `String header = httpURLConnection2.getHeaderFields().toString();`
в нем находится что то подобное

```
{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Cache-Control=[no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json], Date=[Mon, 10 Jul 2017 19:33:04 GMT], Expires=[Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT], Pragma=[no-cache], Server=[nginx/1.11.10], Set-Cookie=[PHPSESSID=tun3co90ia7dplj03nf573c4p3; path=/, usrnm=YnP%2BMucXYelNwLUYcAnycqUKqxrsLF%2F6UBHoGrV5gy81hFmwxdNVrEUgM0CIDpIEgl1FGwMzu9eEKgcsE65s8g%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 09-Aug-2017 19:33:04 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1499715181888], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], X-Android-Selected-Protocol=[http/1.1], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1499715181734], X-Powered-By=[PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21]}
```

как это можно распарсить либо как получить этот header подругому чтоб можно было распарсить
вот сам код

```
try {
                String email = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                URL url2 = new URL(login2);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection2.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection2.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream2 = httpURLConnection2.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("gmc", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream2, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data2 = URLEncoder.encode("myusername", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("mypassword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")+ "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("app_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("4f0n6tlqqkae4revct5bnk59g5", "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter2.write(post_data2);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                bufferedWriter2.flush();
                bufferedWriter2.close();
                outputStream.close();
                outputStream2.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStream inputStream2 = httpURLConnection2.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream2, "UTF-8"));

                while ((line = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                    cookies += line;
                }
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                header = httpURLConnection2.getHeaderFields().toString();
                bufferedReader.close();
                bufferedReader2.close();
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream2.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                httpURLConnection2.disconnect();
```

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman  вы имеете ввиду return httpURLConnection2.getHeaderFields() ?

Comment: у меня не получается через return реализовать не могу понять куда его засунуть

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman посмотрите вопрос еще раз пожалуйста я добавил код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете получить словарь и работать с ним напрямую

```
List<String> cookies = httpURLConnection2.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("usrnm=([^;]+)");
for(String cookie: cookies) {
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cookie);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: почему у меня matcher.fing() = false??? и поэтому у меня не работает     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

Comment: '[PHPSESSID=sksbficuutcg56ojp9ccnmo374; path=/, usrnm=AGVnLkDCMJ88H4XSR4E1D0Vi6iUC1EfBmO%2BZgqBVitGKB%2FqJC2aZ6Q0Fd41LenpbDsSCKGyTjdletBxigj3c%2Fw%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 09-Aug-2017 23:23:58 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.dsdf.com]'

Comment: PHPSESSID=2k324i0cka3eim0ge7l9stm5a5; path=/   куда то девается остальная часть

Comment: если вместо usrnm вписать PHPSESSID он его выводит   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PHPSESSID =([^;]+)"); а вот usrnm  неполучается

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

А что именно Вы хотите ещё парсить и зачем? `getHeaderFields()` и так возвращает словарь `Map<String, List<String>>`, где по ключу Вы можете получить значения хедера. Или же воспользоваться одним из `getHeaderField` методов, чтобы сразу получить конкретное значение.

Но если Вам очень хочется, то для Ваша задача решается с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("(\\S)=\\[(.+?)\\]").matcher(input);
while (match.find()) {
    // match.group(1); -- это имя хедера
    // match.group(2); -- это значение
}
```

Не забудьте сделать `input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);`, чтобы избавиться от фигурных скобок.

**UPD**: для конкретного хедера используйте сразу

```
String value = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
```

или так как предложили в комментариях ниже:

```
String value = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
```

Comment: мне нужно достать usrnm  и Set-Cookie

Comment: как по ключу можно получить значения хедера??

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman а как конкретно что то достать потом оттуда из Set-Cookie напривер usrnm